# Programmatically customize windows 8

Tags: windows-8, taskbar, start-screen

Could I make the Windows 8 Start menu behave more like the task-bar? The functionality I have in mind is to automatically pin running applications to the left most group, and also to create that group at start up.

I know that the most likely answer I will receive is just to change my workflow, but I like using full screen windows and this prevents the task bar from peeking.

This is a very general question but if someone could point me to some resources I would appreciate it very much.

I suppose an alternative solution would be allowing the task-bar to peek over full screen applications, or setting a hot key to pop up the task bar.

Are any of these options possible?

Comment: Even if you could do this pragmatically you would fight with Windows wanting to reorgnaize the Start Screen.  The Start Screen is meant to be changed just like the `Start Menu` was designed to change and list recently used programs.

Comment: [Pragmatically](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pragmatic)?

Comment: @terdon as in a batch file or script that will make the adjustments every time I open or close an application.

Comment: You mean programmatically?

Comment: lol, yes that is what I meant.

Comment: @Griffin no worries :). And speaking of helping the community, lets delete our conversation since it does not add anything to the question. I've deleted my comments but cannot delete yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ***may*** work but you will have to start the program from the Script and the icons will be on the right.

*script.bat*

```
script.vbs prog.exe link
```

*script.vbs*

```
prog = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
lk = WScript.Arguments.Item(1)
Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sLinkFile = "%userprofile%"\start menu\programs\"+prog+".lnk"
Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile)

oLink.TargetPath = lk
oLink.Save
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but, I coy and pasted your code and returned an error : Line 2, Char 35, Expected end of statement, code 800a0401. In the vbs file.

Comment: @Chris I have improved the answer; I added:   prog = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
lk = WScript.Arguments.Item(1)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to force the Windows 8 Start Screen to function like
the Windows 7 Start Menu, a better idea might be to return the Windows 7 functionality
that Microsoft has erased from the Windows 8 desktop.

This requires a third-party product. Below are listed the two products that I consider as being the best.

The free [Classic Start Menu](http://www.classicshell.net/) does a pretty good job and even lets you totally bypass
the Windows 8 Start Screen.

The commercial [Start8 by StarDock](http://www.stardock.com/products/start8/) might be even better, but costs $4.99 (trial available).

Comment: $5 so I don't have to move my mouse as much. Worth every penny. I would have paid more.

Comment: Will the start menu display running applications or just those that have been pinned?

Comment: The start menu will look very similar to that of Windows 7. Applications will be displayed/pinned as always on the taskbar. If you wish, you can even [bring back the Quick Launch bar](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/add-quick-launch-bar-windows-8/).